# How do I stop ASP.NET web api PUT verb returning 500

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm running an ASP.NET Web API application on IIS 7.5. When I try to access anything using the PUT verb, I get a 500 error.

When I run the same code using IIS Express on my local machine I get the response I am expecting.

Worth noting that I was getting the `405 Method not found` response, so I removed WebDav reference in Modules in IIS.

I'm using the controller that Visual Studio gives you when you first create the project:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ambiguous);
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("PUT")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.SeeOther);
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

(with a couple of changes). When I run the POST/GET actions, I get the responses I expect but the PUT one isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739124/iis-7-5-enable-put-and-delete-for-restful-service-extensionless)

Basically the default ExtensionlessUrlHandler does not accept PUT and DELETE verb. Just need to add them in the web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```