# IIS 7.5 Can't use "PUT" - Keep getting 500 Error

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

I have created a simple WebAPI application, I am able to "GET", "POST" without any problems.

Whenever I use a "PUT" I keep getting "IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 500.0 - Internal Server Error".

This works OK on my local machine but not on our hosted web site (through an external provider).

This is the error that i am getting :

```
Server Error in Application "PORTAL.XXXXX.COM"
Internet Information Services 7.5

Error Summary
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred

Detailed Error Information
Module LiveStreamingHandler
Notification MapRequestHandler
Handler ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
Error Code 0x80070585

Requested URL http://portal.XXXXXXXX.com:80/api/Organisation/4/
Physical Path C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hostingsite\httpdocs\Portal\api\Organisation\4\
Logon Method Bearer
Logon User Administrator

Most likely causes:
IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Things you can try:
Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
Verify the permissions for the DLL.
Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439

Links and More Information
This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.
```

Comment: Have a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912922/how-do-i-stop-asp-net-web-api-put-verb-returning-500

Comment: I've tried modifying the Web.Config but it still does not work