# RestSharp asynchronous PUT

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, restsharp

There is one application, the API with access to the database and one application that calls the API with RestSharp.
I implemented all async methods of RestSharp to work generic. So GET, POST, DELETE are all working.The only one I can't get to work is the PUT.

First of all this is my controllers PUT:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public void Put(int id, [FromBody]ApplicationUser value)
{
    string p = value.Email;
}
```

this is my method:

```
 public Task<bool> PutRequestContentAsync<T>(string resource, object id, T resourceObject) where T : new()
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient("http://localhost:54008/api/");
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest($"{resource}/{{id}}", Method.PUT);
        request.AddUrlSegment("id", id);
        request.AddObject(resourceObject);
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        var asyncHandler = client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, r =>
        {
            tcs.SetResult(r.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Completed);
        });

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

and this is my call in a view (all other calls of GET,... are working fine):

```
bool putOk = await new RepositoryCall()
    .PutRequestContentAsync("Values", 2, 
        new ApplicationUser { 
            Email="test@xxxxxxx.de" 
        }
    );
```

with debugging, the response-status is `Completed` but the PUT is never called.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: You are referring to PUT but your repository call reflects DELETE. Probably you copy-pasted wrong piece of code.

Comment: @serhiyb yep, was the wrong method I posted. updated :D

Comment: Which web server did you test it on? IIS/IIS Express?

Comment: the application runs for now directly with visual studio 2015, so IIS Express

Comment: Can you give this answer a try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24791070/5103294 (under your server config, the one that process PUT request, not the sender)

Comment: sure, I give it a try

Comment: @serhiyb, if you are interrested, I posted the answer. problem was the code, not the config. but thanks for your help!

Comment: Cool, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So finally I got my answer myself... (sit yesterday 6 hours and no result, today one more hour and it works)

```
public Task<bool> PutRequestContentAsync<T>(string resource, object id, T resourceObject) where T : new()
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient("http://localhost:54008/api/");
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest($"{resource}/{{id}}", Method.PUT);
    request.AddUrlSegment("id", id);

    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddBody(resourceObject);

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    var asyncHandler = client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, (response) => {
        tcs.SetResult(response.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Completed);
    });
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

the trick was to add a RequestFormat and changing `AddObject` to `AddBody` :)

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, But my controller returns an IActionResult, so I put Task<IActionResult>. but can't figure out how to make the method wait for the task to complete before returning View.

Comment: @RickerSilva I think your problem is how to use async/await? If yes, I think you need to start another question.