# Godaddy windows 2012 VPS doesn't allow PUT ,DELETE for API in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, iis-8

Whenever i try to put or delete method using webapi, it returns 500 internal error! It only allows get and Post method:
I googled all over few days! what i found to change or add `<remove name="WebDAV"/>`
 this tag in `<system.webServer>` .I did but not worked!

I also tried `1.Go to IIS Manager.
2.Click on your app.
3.Go to "Handler Mappings".
4.In the feature list, double click on "WebDAV".
5.Click on "Request Restrictions".
6.In the tab "Verbs" select "All verbs" .
7.Press OK.` found on [IIS 7.5 + enable PUT and DELETE for RESTFul service, extensionless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739124/iis-7-5-enable-put-and-delete-for-restful-service-extensionless)

Everything works in godaddy shared hosting but VPS that i recently got!

My JS:
POST

```
$http.post("/api/ProductsApi/InsertCompanydata/", addCompanyData)
              .then(function (data) {
                  $scope.saveOrUpdateSuccessTxt = 'Successfully Saved!';
              }).catch(function (e) {

              }).then(function () {
                  $scope.saveOrUpdateLoading = false;
              });
```

Put:

```
$http.put("/api/ProductsApi/UpdateCompany/" + $scope.CompanyID, editCompanyData)
              .then(function (data) {

                  $scope.saveOrUpdateSuccessTxt = 'Successfully Updated!';

              }).catch(function (e) {
                  console.log(e.status)

              }).then(function () {
                  $scope.saveOrUpdateLoading = false;
              });
```

API Controller::

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/ProductsApi/InsertCompanydata")]
    public HttpResponseMessage InsertCompanydata(Companyt com)
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "INSERT into Companyt (CompanyName) values (@name)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", com.CompanyName);

            //compare CompanyName
            SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand("sp_CompanyInsertValidation", con);
            com2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CompanyName", com.CompanyName));
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com2);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            int m = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;


            if (m >= 1)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
            }
            else
            {
                con.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }


 [HttpPut]
        [Route("api/ProductsApi/UpdateCompany")]
        public HttpResponseMessage UpdateCompany(int id, Companyt comp)
        {            
            using (SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "UPDATE Companyt  SET CompanyName = @name where CompanyID =@id";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", comp.CompanyName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

                //compare CompanyName
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_CompanyUpdateValidation", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", comp.CompanyName));
                com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                int m = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

                    con.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();

            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

My webconfig portion:

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="IdentitySample.Startup,Inventory" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>

    <!--<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />-->
    <!--<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>

    -->
    <!--<trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>-->
    <!--

    <trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>-->



    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="2880" cookieless="false"></sessionState>
    <!--<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />-->
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

    <!--<trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>-->

    <trust level="Full" originUrl="" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880" />


    </authentication>



    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <machineKey validationKey="1A4DBAA59CCB4BFCEA0CB3485D7809F6E7382E4E7877EDAA26B6A9310A95B659DA061232F757C8F973D24D3EBA4DBC1D08F4E5AC5C1E65454C5150AA49E1C7AC" decryptionKey="F4A8287B30C5596AD89258E31D3F53D078492EF596898BB87A14EBB32FF79968" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="routes.axd" type="AttributeRouting.Web.Logging.LogRoutesHandler, AttributeRouting.Web" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/default.aspx">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/500.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/403.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="RoleManager" />
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      <!-- add this -->
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <!--<handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV"/>

      <add name="AttributeRouting" path="routes.axd" verb="*" type="AttributeRouting.Web.Logging.LogRoutesHandler, AttributeRouting.Web"/>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/><remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>-->
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="AttributeRouting" path="routes.axd" verb="*" type="AttributeRouting.Web.Logging.LogRoutesHandler, AttributeRouting.Web" />
    </handlers>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Have you tried asking Godaddy directly for support?

Comment: yes i chatted with them 4 times but they said that they don't have such support @Remy

Comment: Did you set up your CORS correctly to allow the said methods?

Comment: i did not do anything in my new VPS! How to check CORS in godaddy VPS?

Comment: Seems lame but not sure the reason, if you don't get any response from GoDaddy then you can use `POST` or `HttpPost`for both delete & update too. I can see it's not pure WebAPI & you have custom method name not only verb for entity so should not be aesthetic issue, Technically it is possible.

Comment: Add below tag in web.config to enable CORS. 

<system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>

Comment: it does not work!