# Put request is not working using postman to web api 2 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, postman

I have a method in Api as follows

```
[HttpPut]
        [Route("UpdateTeacher")]
        public IHttpActionResult UpdateTeacher(BusinessLayerTeacher Obj)
        {
            try
            {
                BusinessLayerTeacher obj = new BusinessLayerTeacher ();
                string status = BusinessLayerObject.UpdateTeacher(TeacherObj);
                return Ok(status);
            }
            catch
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        }
```

Now in post man i am sending the put request to update the teacher object. 
It is not triggering this updateTeacher() method.

Comment: What does the URL look like in Postman? What host/port is the server running on? What happens instead?

Comment: Check if Put Request are allowed in your IIS/Server. Seems like your server is rejecting them before passing to Web API

Comment: As it seems you don't use anywhere the value you Put, `Obj`. Each time you try to update a record, you create a new `BusinessLayerTeacher ` and you try to update this.

Comment: How to know wether my serve ris accepting put requests

Comment: See this question on how to enable PUT. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6739124/108847

Comment: Thank you Fishcake. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating a new BusinessLayerTeacher object inside the method, which looks suspect when you are already passing in BusinessLayerTeacher as a parameter.

Maybe the route mapping isn't working because you're not passing in the right data in the request body.

Maybe you should be using TeacherObj as the parameter type?

Have a review and give that a try, good luck :-)