# ASP.NET Core with IIS - HTTP Verb Not Allowed

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We have an **ASP.NET Core 2.0** web site that also presents a couple of simple **Web API** methods for UI enhancement purposes.

The **Web API** calls work as expected when running locally under **IIS Express**, but when we deploy to our **IIS 8.5** production web server, we get the following error when making HTTP `DELETE` and `PUT` requests...

```
405 Method Not Allowed
```

After some web searching, we have found several posts suggesting the removal of the IIS **WebDAV** module.  We have disabled this in IIS (it is our server), and we have also tried the following:

- Disabled *WebDAV*
- Enabled *WebDev* and set `Allow verb filtering = False`
- Set the *Hander Mappings* to allow *All Verbs* in the *Request Restrictions* settings for: `aspNetCore`, `WebDAV` and `ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0`

None of the above steps have resolved our problem.

Any advice/direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whilst removing WebDAV may solve your issue, you may be wondering (like I was), what is WebDAV and what is it used for?

I found this page which helps explain it:

https://www.cloudwards.net/what-is-webdav/

Answer (score 82):

This was what worked for me (netcore 2.0)

```html
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Found here: https://www.ryadel.com/en/error-405-methods-not-allowed-asp-net-core-put-delete-requests/

Comment: It worked but this made my website so slow in .net core 2.1 RC, I had to remove this instruction

Comment: @Alexandre This setting should really only be necessary for a service site. A website should respond to GET and POST by default, and really should need nothing else. If you are doing REST calls to your website, I would suggest off-loading these calls to a sub-application, and app pool that can be managed separately.

Comment: I tried literally everything on my .NET 5 app and this fixed it.  I'm doing a Blazor WASM app that is hosted on a Blazor web server.  I can finally deploy everything to Azure and it works just as it does locally.  Thank you.

Answer (score 69):

After hours of research and trial and error, the fix seems to be pretty simple.  Add a `Web.config` file to your *.NET Core 2.0* application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <!-- To customize the asp.net core module uncomment and edit the following section. 
         For more info see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=838655 -->
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="aspNetCore" />
            <remove name="WebDAV" />
            <!-- I removed the following handlers too, but these
                 can probably be ignored for most installations -->
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
            <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />

            <add name="aspNetCore" 
                 path="*" 
                 verb="*" 
                 modules="AspNetCoreModule" 
                 resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" 
                    arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" 
                    stdoutLogEnabled="false"
                    stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I try to publish with a web.config file I just get an error near the end of the publish process. I read elsewhere that ASP.NET Core 2.0 doesn't support web.config files any more. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you publishing - in Visual Studio, VSTS or something else?  As notes below we are running in IIS 8.5 and .NET Core 2.0 without a problem.

Comment: @DickieWatkins, in my case, with Asp.Net Core 2.1, and deploying from Visual Studio, a web.config was autogenerated on the server as part of the deployment process. If you just take that file, copy it to your project, add the `<modules><remove name="WebDAVModule"/></modules>` as shown in this answer, then just set the build rule to "Copy Always," then in future deployments that same webconfig will be used, but appended to automatically. But, this is likely dependent on your deployment method and whether you're running IIS.

Comment: Thanks a lot it took me just half a day to realize that my server has the problem and the iis is the problem and not the app itself

Comment: I am using Kestrel, does this solution apply?

Comment: Found that only this was needed for me: <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\CCPOAdmin.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
      <modules>
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      </modules>

Comment: None of this works for me.  I am using .NET Core 3.1, IIS express 10.0 and Visual studio 2019.  I can't get http PUT to work. It's driving me crazy! Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I got the 405 error for .Net 5 Web API PUT and DELETE calls. I tried multiple solutions like removing WebDAV (Turn Windows features on or off -> IIS -> World Wide Web Services -> Common HTTP feature -> WebDAV Publishing) doesn't work, editing WebDAV entry in "Handler Mappings" messed up the application.

**Solution**

In IIS, select the application

1. Add rules to allow HTTP verbs in Request Filtering (But this alone doesn't work).
2. Go to "Modules", then select the "WebDAV Publishing" module and remove it.
3. Go to "Handler Mappings", then select the "WebDAV" and remove it.
4. in cmd run IISRESET

Comment: For me, with .NET 5, only steps 2 & 3 were necessaries to sort it out. Many thanks

Comment: I literally don't know how to say thank you to you... You saved my job. I have been trying to solve this issue for the last 4 days and nights and found your answer just a few hours before the deadline. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

To prevent WebDav from getting enabled at all, **remove** the following entry from the **ApplicationHost.config**:

```
<add name="WebDAVModule" />
```

The entry is located in the modules section.

Exact location of the config:
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

This worked well for me in .Net Core 2.1

Comment: Better to add the "remove" node instead; as shown in Manuel Alves' answer. If your app is a sub app, it can still pick up this setting from a parent web.config. The selected answer has a lot more code than is technically needed to simply allow all verbs.

Comment: @iGanja: depending on the deployment process the web.config gets overwritten or you dont want to wrestle with it at all in .net core. It is also advisable to dont add unused features webserver wide for security.

Answer (score 7):

Add the following lines to your web.config file. That does it.

[image: Web.config screenshot]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
      <handlers>
      
            <remove name="WebDAV" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DELETE,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Ftms.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6):

Remove the WebDAV Publishing from IIS server. Its come under the Internet Infromation service -> Common Http Features

https://ignas.me/tech/405-method-not-allowed-iis/

Comment: Control Panel -> Uninstall Program -> Turn Windows features on or off -> IIS -> World Wide Web Services -> Common HTTP feature -> WebDAV Publishing.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I resolved the issue after I add `requireAccess="None"` to `aspNetCore` handler

Like this :

```
<add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" />
```

Comment: I added this to web.config and it worked. Thanks

Comment: is there a way how to add this to web config automatically during publishing?

Comment: this worked for me thank you can you please explain about this?what does it do?

Answer (score 1):

For me, I resolved the issue after I noticed I was trying to post to the client domain instead of the API. [facepalm]

Comment: i searched for hours and seeing this comment saved my day. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't even have a mapping for aspnetcore under Handler Mappings in IIS. It made me open Visual Studio Installer and install *Development time IIS support* under .NET cross-platform development. Then, the aspnetcore handler mapping showed up in IIS.

[image: VSI]

Comment: so basically site is deployed to IIS so you can disable webdav there?

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing with recent ASP.NET Core version and using development server it's likely that it's not a WebDAV issue at all.

Make sure that your routes and `HttpDelete`/`HttpPut` attributes are set correctly. Otherwise you'll get the same or similar errors if the method is simply mismatched (e.g. route to a HttpGet one was chosen).

Answer (score 0):

After long research on the internet, I solved it as follows;

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="ModSecurity IIS (64bits)" />
        <remove name="ModSecurity IIS (32bits)" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

To prevent WebDav from getting enabled at all, remove or comment the following entry from the ApplicationHost.config:

```
<add name="WebDAVModule" />
```

The entry is located in the modules section.

Exact location of the config:
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

This worked well for me in .Net Core 2.2