# Debugging ASP.NET Core Application on IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to debug an issue with my app running on IIS that only manifests itself when in release mode.  The gist of the issue is that I'm getting a 405 error only when I'm not debugging my application from the IDE itself, which smells to me like a permissions issue, but I would like to at least try to step through the code and be sure that is what is going on.

I know the general steps for attaching to IIS.  Go to Debug > Attach to Process > select w3wcp.exe.  When it does that, it seems load up a bunch of symbols for various dll's.  The problem is that I don't have the symbols for my actual program getting loaded, and I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  If I place a breakpoint in my code, I shows up as a red circle with an exclamation mark on the bottom right saying "The breakpoint will currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

How can I go about getting the debugger to load my symbols?  I tried going to Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols and then tried manually adding paths to my dll (I entered it as "C:\Path\to\my\app.dll", minus the quotes).  Can anyone give me some pointers on how to get the debug information loaded?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but have you seen [ASP.NET Core with IIS - HTTP Verb Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188895/)?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x ASP.NET Core apps are hosted in Kestrel process, not IIS worker process.