# Getting 405 error when making a DELETE request from an asp.net core app

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, http-status-code-405

I have an asp.net core API, from which I am trying to make a DELETE request to another asp.net core API. When I call the first API I receive a 405 error when it makes the delete call to the second API. I've tried the solution found here; [ASP.NET Core with IIS - HTTP Verb Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188895/asp-net-core-with-iis-http-verb-not-allowed), and several other related solutions without success. I've also tried [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests (CORS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2) in my Startup.cs file, however nothing seemed to change.

Here is my delete endpoint:

```
    [HttpDelete("MyDeleteEndpoint")]
    public async Task MyDeleteEndpoint([FromRoute] string id)
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();

        var response = await http.DeleteAsync("https://myserver:443/api/mycontroller/{id});

        //do more stuff
    }
```

Here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is my ConfigureServices and my Configure methods in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

  services.AddCors(options =>
  {
      options.AddPolicy("mypolicy",
      builder =>
      {
          builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
      });
  });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
         app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseCors("mypolicy");
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: What is the detail error message? Have you configured `services.AddCors` in the second api project? You need to configure cors in the api which you want to send request to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem before.  The only way to resolve it that I found was to explicitly list the methods that were allowed in the `web.config`.

Here is an excerpt from the `web.config`.  Note that you probably don't want all of these settings but I'm leaving them in for brevity:

```
...
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="authorization,content-type" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
...
```

Without explicitly adding the `DELETE` request to the allowed methods, the request was automatically rejected before it even got to my code.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is being hosted under IIS, include this line in the Web.Config file

```
<configuration> 
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
       <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```