# How to remove WebDAV module in WebAPI core?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a simple WebAPI using .Net Core 2.2. While I use POSTMAN to hit the action method with PUT HttpVerb, I get 
**405 - Method not allowed**
message. While I checked for this online, the suggestion was to remove the WebDAV module from the Web.config. But in the .Net Core WebAPI, there is launchSettings.json and appsettings.json for the configuration.

Kindly help me as to how to set the setting in either of the aforementioned config files to remove the WebDAV module.

I'm new to .Net Core.

I tried to create a Web.Config and used the below code to remove the WebDAV module, but no luck

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

I haven't done this is WebAPI without using .Net Core. The request from POSTMAN is expected to hit the PUT method.

Kindly help.

How to convert this setting to JSON format for appSettings.json

Comment: Do you host the application on IIS ?  Try [this](https://ignas.me/tech/405-method-not-allowed-iis/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50624155/5751404) .

Comment: Thanks Nan Yu. I use IIS express to run the Web API locally. I use POSTMAN to test the locally run Web API. Kindly help on this scenario.

Comment: Show you related codes , i remember iis express by default support put verbs

Comment: @NanYu here is the code `// PUT: api/Employee/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public Employee Put(int id, [FromBody] Employee employee)
        {
            var empList = GetStdEmployeeList();

            empList.Where(iter => iter.Id == id).FirstOrDefault().Name = employee.Name;
            empList.Where(iter => iter.Id == id).FirstOrDefault().Salary = employee.Salary;
            return empList.Where(iter => iter.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }`

Comment: Do you need the Startup.cs code too?

Comment: Exact same issue... did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem; PUT was enabled in IIS Express, which was our testing environment, and WebDAV was installed on the production environment which disabled PUT and DELETE verbs. This resulted in an error on the production server: `405 HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed`

This is solved by adding a `web.config` configuration file to the project that disables WebDAV -- don't try to add this to the `app.settings` JSON file.

`web.config` file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```