# How to remove WebDav in ASP.NET Core Web API in .NET8

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Core API with an EF database, and I offer a delete REST endpoint. It works well when testing it in the Swagger interface, but when I try from another application using Http requests, I get a MethodNotAllowed Http status.

Now I found that in order to resolve that, you have to add a web.config file to your project folder and include the following tag ([How to remove WebDav in Startup.cs ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60640131/how-to-remove-webdav-in-startup-cs-asp-net-core)) :

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
```

Unfortunately that does not do it for my API. Maybe is there something else to do in .NET 8 ?

My web.config file is located at the root of my project and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thanks a lot for any input

Comment: I am pretty sure that you also need to explicitly ALLOW the DELETE verb.  Review some of the answer on this post for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440277/how-do-i-enable-http-put-and-delete-for-asp-net-mvc-in-iis

Comment: Is there any progress to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this issue as well, the file that you need to modify is:

> {project_root}.vs{project_name}\config\applicationhost.config

And then you need to modify this tag:

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0" />
```

Add "PUT,DELETE" to the verb attribute.

I also added a web.config file at the root of my folder and added the following tag as a child of system.webServer but honestly I lost track of this after struggling for hours and don't quite remember if both changes are neccessary but just in case:

```
<handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
```