# How do you allow PUTs and DELETEs in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, put, http-verbs

I'm trying to get a simple MVC page to `PUT` to my Controller. `GET` and `POST` will work fine, but I am doing an Update, so a `PUT` is more applicable, and it's calling the WebAPI backend with a PUT just fine.

I've created a new base project and replicated the issue too. If I POST a form it is caught by the controller. If I change the same controller endpoint to `HttpPut` and change the form to `Put`, it doesn't. Instead a `GET` is called!

I'm aware of the WebDAV fix in `web.config`, but this is Core 3.1, so there is no `web.config`. Does anyone know how to affect that same WebDAV fix in 3.1? If that is in fact the issue.

I've replicated the issue with this minimal code:

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new IndexViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPut] // Change this to HttpPost
    public IActionResult Index(IndexViewModel model)
    {
        Debug.Print(model.Text);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

**IndexViewModel.cs**

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IndexViewModel
<div class="text-center">
    <form asp-action="Index" method="put"> @*Change this to method="post"*@
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
        <input type="text" asp-for="Text" />
        <button type="submit">Go</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This stack article is for .net core 2 but maybe help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188895/asp-net-core-with-iis-http-verb-not-allowed

Comment: Thanks, but WebDAV isn't a think in core 3, and I now think it's only relevant to WebApi, which works fine. The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054165/using-put-method-in-html-form that this has been marked a duplicate of nails it. In fact, I should make this an answer