# 403 Forbidden Error for .Net Core 3.1 Web Api only for Delete & PUT method

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, web-hosting

Application in .Net Core 3.1 and angular which working perfectly in locally. I hosted same application one of the hosting provider.

I am getting error "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied." for PUT & DELETE methods in web api response. I don't know why GET & POST methods are working in same application.

[ASP.NET Core with IIS - HTTP Verb Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188895/asp-net-core-with-iis-http-verb-not-allowed)

Above link have somewhat same issue but getting 405 error. Solution given in same thread also tried but not working for me.

Please help on the same.

Comment: 403 forbidden means authorization failure. Have you configured any Auth service in web API?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I raised a ticket to my hosting provider. They made some settings and after that its working fine.

Comment: can you tell us what settings they change?

Answer (score 0):

Are your frontend in angular? If yes, you have to add auth bearer header for put and delete correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      </modules>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\XXXXXXXXXXX.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```