# Upload image with textual information json and wcf

Tags: c#, json

Hi Iwant to Upload image with textual information json and wcf the image contain a title and descrption any help please

**the function**
    which implemet the below interface i am working with json an wcf

```
 public wsResultImage InsertPhoto(Stream JsonDataStream)
            {
                wsResultImage results = new wsResultImage();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(JsonDataStream);
                string JSONdata = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // bool logged;
                // ..then convert the string into a single "wsOrder" record.
                JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                wsImage photoo = jss.Deserialize<wsImage>(JSONdata);  
                //  byte[] bytes= (byte[]) (photoo.GetImage).ToArray();
                if (photoo == null)
                {
                    results.id = photoo.GetId;
                    results.titlee = photoo.GetTitle;
                    results.imag = photoo.GetImage;
                    results.descriptionn = photoo.GetDescrption;
                    results.message = "all  fields are required";
                    return results;
                }
                FamissimaDataContext dc = new FamissimaDataContext();
                /*  imagees photo = (from p
                              in dc.imagees

                                   select p).FirstOrDefault();  */
                // byte[] bytes= (byte[]) (photoo.GetImage).ToArray();
                //  string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                //  where (photoo.GetId = p.id)
                byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(photoo.GetImage);
                imagees newPhoto = new imagees()
                {
                    id = photoo.GetId,
                    // imagee = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(photoo.GetImage),
                    //   imagee = imageBytes,
                    title = photoo.GetTitle,

                    description = photoo.GetDescrption,
                };


                dc.imagees.InsertOnSubmit(newPhoto);
                dc.SubmitChanges();
                // Console.WriteLine("Hello C# World :-) ");
                results.message = "Success";
                // result.Exception = "";



                return results;


            }
```

**the interface:**

```
  [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method= "Post", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "uploadimage")]
    wsResultImage InsertPhoto(Stream JsonDataStream);
```

Comment: You can use Base64 encoding to convert the image data into a string. The rest is straightforward.

Comment: please give me  an exemple because  i tried a lot but I haven't find a soloution  :/

Comment: Can you show us what you did?

Comment: how can I  share  the code I am  new in this forum  :/

Comment: @NadeemAfana  i shared the code  any help and thnx

Comment: Does this line `wsImage photoo = jss.Deserialize<wsImage>(JSONdata);` execute with no errors ?

Comment: yes without any error  but the problem  i am  using a json post which  help me to test I have the follwing error:
An exception was thrown: Le serveur distant a retourné une erreur : (405) Méthode non autorisée.

Comment: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed

Comment: There seems to be configuration problem on your IIS server.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147181/405-method-not-allowed-in-iis7-5-for-put-method might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that helps you:

Note I truncated the encoded string since it's too long.

```
void Main()
{   
    string json = "{Title: 'Image title', Description: 'Description', Base64Data : 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAAQCAYAAADNo/U5AAAACXBIWXMAAA......'}";
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var picture = js.Deserialize<Picture>(json);



    // Now deserialize the Base64 encoded picture.
    picture.Data = Convert.FromBase64String(picture.Base64Data);

    File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\test.png", picture.Data);
}

class Picture
{
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public byte[] Data {get; set;}
    public string Base64Data {get; set;}
}
```