# Enable Http PUT for .net 3.5 application. getting error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, iis-7.5, ashx, http-put

I am facing an issue while posting http using request type PUT, it is not enabled on IIS, can someone help me on how to enable PUT request type via web.config changes.

Failed Request Tracing logs:

```
<failedRequest url="http://localhost:80/.../TestHandler.ashx"
               siteId="1"
               appPoolId="DefaultAppPool"
               processId="10708"
               verb="PUT"
               remoteUserName=""
               userName=""
               tokenUserName="NT AUTHORITY\IUSR"
               authenticationType="anonymous"
               activityId="{00000000-0000-0000-3D85-0580000000FE}"
               failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
               statusCode="405"
               triggerStatusCode="405"
               timeTaken="0"
               xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
               >
```

**EDIT:**
I don't have WebDAV module installed on my machine, and one of my colleague have it installed on his machine. Tried the below mentioned solution and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faizan Please try solution mentioned at 
["405 method not allowed" in IIS7.5 for "PUT" method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147181/405-method-not-allowed-in-iis7-5-for-put-method)

It states that 
Sometimes you need to remove WebDAV from modules and from handlers of the system.webServer section. Here my suggested configuration:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```