# The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/' is not allowed using php on iis 7

Tags: javascript, php, iis

How to resolve the issue i am using windows server 2008 with php 5.5.1 and urlrewrite 2

The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/' is not allowed using php on iis 7

Comment: What do you mean by `not allowed`

Comment: data is not posting to the page while i submit , give me the cosole error like 405 Method Not Allowed..

Comment: i am using php with iis 7 on windows server 2008 ..

Comment: Can you post the full line code?

Comment: its not just one line code my whole application reports are not working , before that it works fine but i upgraded the php version and again downgraded thats why it show this error , i dont understand is this the server error or something else .

Comment: i already checked on another server it works fine , i think something wrong with server configuration , but dont know how to resolve

Comment: Take a look here: [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/258399/how-to-tell-iis7-to-allow-post-to-a-text-file-to-solve-405)

Comment: And also this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147181/405-method-not-allowed-in-iis7-5-for-put-method)

Comment: still not fix , please help me