# IIS Not allowing put for one specific service

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-8

We've done a fresh install of IIS 8.5 on a Windows server. On IIS we've deployed 4 or 5 WCF services.

Some of these services have `PUT` requests (delete will follow soon). But we run into an issue. On one of those services `PUT` returns "Method not allowed" 405 errors.

Now, note that the config for all the services regarding handlers is 100% the same (I've verified this a couple of times now).

Other services also consume `PUT` Requests, these also work fine. When I do a `HEAD` request with postman I can only see `GET` allowed for the request which should also exist as `PUT`.

(e.g. one has a WebGet attribute and one a WebInvoke configured with PUT) both on the same URI. Locally when debugging from Visual Studio, the `PUT` requests work fine, however, deployed we can't get it to work for this single endpoint.

The only difference I can see is that our `PUT` request which does not work consumes a JSON body, the other only looks at URI params...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6223774/4074041

Comment: I'll look into it, but WebDav is not installed

Answer (score 0):

You can **add** `ExtensionlessUrlHandler` through web.config like that:

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
   <remove name="WebDAV" />
   <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
   <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"
      path="*."
      verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
      modules="IsapiModule"
      scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64"
      responseBufferLimit="0" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: Yes I've tried this.

Note that it DOES WORK for other services with same config

Comment: so, i can offer you one **hard way**: check which handler get POST requests, and add into your web.config `custom httphandler` with standart IIS handler but allowing `PUT` request.

Comment: I'll try to figure that out.