# What alternative do I have to avoid 405 Method Not Allowed error when using Put or Delete method in Web Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, put, http-status-code-405, http-delete

What alternative do I have to avoid 405 Method Not Allowed error when using Put or Delete method in Web API?

I know there are a lot of solutions that specifically mention removing WebDAV from IIS, or disabling it from the Web.config, or other similar options
For Example:
["405 method not allowed" in IIS7.5 for "PUT" method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147181/405-method-not-allowed-in-iis7-5-for-put-method) and 
[ASP.NET Web API - PUT & DELETE Verbs Not Allowed - IIS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8)

But I have had multiple situations where these were either not viable solutions or they simply didn't work.

Comment: Shared environments for example where people are actually using WebDAV, but like I mentioned, that also did not work in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use Post instead of the Put or Delete method, you can do this by adding some decorators to the functions:

For Example:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Users/Update")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutUser(User user)
    {...
```

The [HttpPost] decorator just indicates that the function is a Post.
And the Route is going to override the default routing in your WebApiConfig.cs.

I hope this makes it easier for someone in the future.