# How make a request in the browser to a DELETE http method in ASP.NET (.NET FRAMEWORK)

Tags: c#, asp.net, middleware, .net-framework-version, http-method

In `laravel` or some `express.js` libs add middleware to check if a field is given called `_Method` which will override the actual http method of the http request on arrival of the server, because the browser only supports `POST` and `GET`.

Does `ASP.NET (.NET Framework)` contain a build-in middleware like those I just mentioned, I couldn't find anything online.

If so, how do I use it or do you know such an atricle.
If not, how can I create such a middleware myself.
I could not create one myself, because the `HttpRequest` in the `HttpContext` is `readonly` and the `HttpMethod` in the `HttpRequest` is `readonly` aswell.

Or is the only choice to use `preventDefault()` and/or `ajax` to send (for example) a `DELETE` request via `javascript`?

Comment: There are some in built modules on web server which prevents certain http verbs. In IIS that module is WebDAVModule. If this module is present in application running on IIS, DELETR web requests are blocked. So it needs to be removed from the application to allow DELETE requests. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147181/405-method-not-allowed-in-iis7-5-for-put-method

Comment: https://ignas.me/tech/405-method-not-allowed-iis/

Comment: The delete api works fine, I tested it with postman. The question is about how I can access that api using browsers.

Comment: You can use Ajax for making API calls from browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I found that later in the chain of `ASP.NET` the `HttpContext` Changes into `HttpContextBase`. This context contains `GetHttpMethodOverride()`.
I looked the Method up on github, because it's [open source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/HttpRequestExtensions.cs) and `ASP.NET` does contain a middleware such as mentioned.
You can override the actual http method using the key `X-HTTP-Method-Override` in either the `Header`, `Form` or `Query string` and the actual http method must be `POST` for the middleware to even consider a http method override.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to assign [HttpDelete] attribute to your function in the controller or API. for example:

```
[HttpDelete]
public JsonResult MyDeleteFunction(int id)
{
    //Write your delete code here
    return Json("some responses");
}
```

Then in client-side, you can use ajax to do the delete request.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ControllerName/MyDeleteFunction',
    dataType: "json",
    type: "DELETE",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({id: 123}),
    async: true,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but I mentioned ajax in the question. I still am wondering if there is a middleware such as those mentioned in the question,if it is possible to make one yourself or whether ajax is the only way to go.