# ASP.NET Web Site Not Allowing Axios PUT Access (405 Method Not Allowed)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, axios, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've got a controller set up and working for all of my `GET` requests, but when it comes to the `PUT` requests my Web Site (*not a Web App*, if that makes any difference) is returning a `405`.

I've got the route defined in my `Global.asax Application_Start()` with the other routes, and it's the first one, so it should be evaluated first (if my understanding is correct):

```cs
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls
            | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
            | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute("FilteredSpecialOrders",
        routeTemplate: "api/sales/filteredRequests",
        defaults: new { controller = "Sales", action = "filteredRequests" });

    // subsequent routes are here
}
```

My `SalesController` has a method with the right attributes for type of request (`Put`) and the action name that matches my `routeTemplate`, as well as the `[FromBody]` attribute on the parameter:

```cs
[HttpPut, ActionName("filteredRequests")]
public IHttpActionResult PutSpecialOrders([FromBody] RequestFilter filter)
{ 
    // do the needful
}
```

...and my client side code creates the body of the message (`filter`) as a JavaScript `object` and sends the `.put` requests via axios:

```js
getFilteredRequests: async function () {
    let filter = {
        name: this.name,
         age: this.yearsOld,
        /* other name/value pairs of course */
    };

    const response = await axios.put(salesApi + 'filteredRequests', filter);
    let data = response.data;
    return data;
}
```

...but I'm always getting back a `405 - Method Not Allowed.`  What am I forgetting? I'm not sure how the JSON object that gets sent in the body is serialized into my `RequestFilter` object - does that happen automagically or do I need to define that somewhere?  I've made sure that the names are the same on both ends, but other than that...

Comment: Check your IIS `web.config`, you likely have WebDAV still enabled, which inserts itself before application code to handle `PUT` requests.

Comment: what am I looking for specifically?  `WebDAV` or some other value?  Because there's nothing about WebDAV in there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147181/405-method-not-allowed-in-iis7-5-for-put-method

Comment: If you'll post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my web.config to remove the WebDAV bits per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26003440/127888) - but I also had to switch my pipeline from `classic` mode to `integrated` to get it to work.