# After uninstalling WebDav on Windows Server 2016 it pops back to life after a day

Tags: windows, iis, server, webdav

We host an API that needs PUT/DELETE verbs to interact and this thing keeps coming up.
At first i figured out I need to ditch webdav to fix the 405 error and went for the solutions described here: ["405 method not allowed" in IIS7.5 for "PUT" method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147181/405-method-not-allowed-in-iis7-5-for-put-method)
I removed handler, module and edited web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="BundleModule" />
      <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
      <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Now the tricky part: I removed webDav with the add/remove Feature and completly deinstalled it and thats it for the day.
But when I login the server and test the verbs on the next day, the error is back and the feature is back installed on the server. I checked the log files for reboots and updates and found nothing peculiar.
Has anyone any idea what I am doing wrong? Any hints are much apprecicated.

Comment: Why you remove webdav module instead of uninstalling it if you don't use it? Find the entry corresponding to the request file suffix in the handler mapping. Edit it and click request restrictions, check verbs to make sure it can accept PUT method.

Comment: We tried completyle uninstalling it via add/remove feature as described in the question above. We dont know exactly why this happens but we think, its related to the deployment process. Maybe a local configuration somehow reinstalls the whole package (but w/o restarting the whole machine). I will keeps this up-to-date when I have further information.

Comment: Do you have any updates about this issue ?

Comment: Nope, the issue still exists. Every release webdav is back on the map. We remove it manually everytime.

Comment: any news about this point ? We thought it was the install of dotnet core hosting, but no... we are really worried about this.

Comment: It was the webconfig all over. Its the strange MS way to config via text and UI. You always gonna have issues. So triplecheck your webconfig.