# How do you deploy ABP.IO application template projects?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, abp

I have some tiered ABP.IO application template project deployment questions - but they may be ASP.NET Core deployment questions.

**Background**

I'm a bit confused as to whether I need to create `appsettings.Production.json` files to mirror the `appsettings.json` files in my class library projects (`MyProduct.Application`, `MyProduct.Application.Contracts`, etc.) AND my four ASP.NET projects (`MyProduct.HttpApi.Host`, `MyProduct.IdentityServer`, `MyProduct.Web`, and `MyProduct.Web.Public`) OR whether I just need to create them for ONLY the four ASP.NET projects and make sure that the settings that are in the class library projects are represented in the ones for the ASP.NET projects.

**Questions**

1. Should I create appsettings.Production.json files in my class
   library/DLL projects?
2. If yes to 1, will the launchSettings.json file be the right place to
   ensure that the libraries are built with the production
   configuration?
3. If yes to 2, are there any considerations when deploying to
   production? I know I need to use an environment variable on the
   server.
4. If no to 1 or 2, how do I build my *libraries* to use the production
   configuration?
5. Is it possible to replace the client secrets wherever they may
   appear? It would seem like it would be necessary but there's no help
   on this in the documentation.  Are there any considerations toward
   doing this? Is a simple search and replace of all the default
   secrets sufficient or are there code changes necessary?
6. Is it possible to replace all references to localhost with the FQDN
   of the respective site (Host/API, IdentityServer, Web, Web.Public)?
   The application template would require this, correct? I am doing an
   IIS deployment currently - not a Docker or Kubernetes deployment.
7. What else am I missing?

Thanks for taking the time to comment. If you have a resource to share with me, please do. I cannot find a deployment guide or checklist on the ABP Framework site, ABP Commercial site, Community Forum, or Discord channel.

**UPDATE**

I have been through these two resources and I am a lot more educated about configuration in ASP.NET Core but I still cannot find the answer to my question about configuring class libraries in production. 1 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0 2 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0

**FINAL UPDATE**

Eventually I just had to figure things out but Omer's answers make a lot of sense in hindsight.

My solution was to add the `appsettings.Production.json` files to each of the deployable projects as suggested below.  You can read Omer's answer for details.  I pretty much did everything that Omer suggested but I had not thought about the one shot seeding of the Identity Server database tables. That was truly helpful. My final hurdle was figuring out a way to perform DB Migrations on my local DB instance and my remote servers with just a click.

Through various posts, I eventually figured out that I could use the Launch Profile editor buried under the Debug section of the DbMigrator project properties, to create myself two Launch Profiles. I have one for local development and one for production - although through this mechanism, I don't see why you couldn't create one for each part of your staging pipeline.

It should be noted that I deleted the default profile which was named using the project name/namespace.

Here is the Launch Profile editor screen for the Development profile:

[image: Development profile]

And here is the Launch Profile editor screen for the Production profile:

[image: Production profile]

Of primary importance is the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` environment variable in development and the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production` environment variable in production.

Exiting the editor produces the `Properties` folder and the contained
`launchSettings.json` file.

[image: launchSettings.json file]

You could create this folder and file yourself without going through the editor. Here is the text of that file:

```js
{
  "profiles": {
    "EnvironmentConfiguration.Cli (Development)": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "EnvironmentConfiguration.Cli (Production)": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I want to run a schema migration, I can simply select the DbMigrator project as the startup project...

[image: Startup Project Selection]

...and I will have two launch profiles in my debug menu:

[image: Profile Selection]

Does anyone know of a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using ABP with Blazor Wasm and IdentityServer is not seperated. So I am publishing only .Host and .Blazor projects.

1. No, you only need them for published projects  (.Host, .Web, .Blazor etc)

> Should I create appsettings.Production.json files in my class
> library/DLL projects?

4. Libraries are not standalone projects. They are used by other projects (By .Host project or they can be used by another library project) So, they will take these configuration settings from live application (.Host, .Web, .Blazor etc)

> If no to 1 or 2, how do I build my libraries to use the production
> configuration?

5. These keys are using by IdentityServer and I think they are seeded to Database on initial migration. If you want to change them, you need to change them from appsettings.json files and change value in database also. By the way, it is encrypted and you need to change value in DB with new encrypted value. (https://support.abp.io/QA/Questions/441/About-changing-client-secrets)

> Is it possible to replace the client secrets wherever they may
> appear? It would seem like it would be necessary but there's no help     on this in the documentation. Are there any considerations toward     doing this? Is a simple search and replace of all the default     secrets sufficient or are there code changes necessary?

6. Change "localhost" values to your FQDN in all appsettings.json files. Also there should be some changes in database for IdentityServer. Because in the initial migration, it is written on DB.
   [dbo].[IdentityServerClientCorsOrigins].[Origin]
   [dbo].[IdentityServerClientPostLogoutRedirectUris].[PostLogoutRedirectUri]  [dbo].[IdentityServerClientRedirectUris].[RedirectUri]

> Is it possible to replace all references to localhost with the FQDN
> of the respective site (Host/API, IdentityServer, Web, Web.Public)?
> The application template would require this, correct? I am doing an
> IIS deployment currently - not a Docker or Kubernetes deployment.

7. Do not forget to install SSL. If you are using Cloudflare disable SSL from Cloudflare (If you have also in server) Because it may conflict.
   Another important thing is to remove Webdav if you are using IIS. Because Webdav occurs error for put request. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59235862/2178028)
   Also, I dont know why but for the first publish of Blazor projects, it gives 403 error for .dll files in ISS. Then I follow this link (https://www.eugenechiang.com/2021/12/12/failed-to-find-a-valid-digest-in-the-integrity-attribute-for-resource-in-blazor-app/) and problem is solved.

> What else am I missing?

Comment: Thanks Omer. I appreciate you elaborating on my questions. I am still at the phase in my development where I can delete the database and reseed it using the new client secrets. But, I have other ABP.IO projects  where knowing how to change the client secrets after the fact will be greatly beneficial. I am going to select your answer as the answer but there is one nuance I will elaborate on  below - running DB migrations on production or at least on a remote server. I will share my solution and I'd appreciate it if you could critique it or suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

actually configuration of development mode different from production mode so to handle this you must use appsetting.production.json

answer for first question is no, because all projects use ui project settings by dependency injection

Comment: Thanks. You were first but you did not come close to answering all my questions.