# Authorize on IIS say 405 method not allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis

My AddIdentityServices code is

```
public static IServiceCollection AddIdentityServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
{
    services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(opt =>
    {    
        opt.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        opt.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    })
     .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
     .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
    .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["TokenKey"]));

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
    {
        opt.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = key,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
        };
    }).AddIdentityCookies();
    services.AddAuthorization(opt =>
    {

    });
    services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, IsHostRequirementHandler>();
    services.AddScoped<TokenService>();
    return services;
}
```

My CreateToken code is

```
public string CreateToken(AppUser user)
{
    var role_name =   _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
    var claim = new List<Claim> {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
        new Claim (ClaimTypes.Role,role_name.ToString())
      };
    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["TokenKey"]));
    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claim),
        Expires = DateAndTime.Now.AddDays(10),
        SigningCredentials = creds,     
    };
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}
```

Authorize code in controller is

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[HttpPut, Route("setAction")]
public async Task<IActionResult> setAction(RequestVehicle requestVehicle)
{
    return ...
}
```

This code is ok and in my local system(windows 10), Admin user can call setAction function and everything is fine.

But But when publish my project on server (windows server 202,IIS 10.0.2) this function say error : `405 Method Not Allowed`

[image: My Request Data]

Why IIS say error 405?

I add role name to claim `new Claim (ClaimTypes.Role,role_name.ToString())` I don't know if this is right or not

Comment: HTTP 405 means the server is expecting one method (e.g. POST) but you are calling it with another (e.g. GET). How are you calling this method?

Comment: @DavidG i call with PUT Method... and this code in my local computer is ok.

Comment: @DavidG I add picture of request data

Comment: If you remove the role in the Authorize tag do you get a 200? If you remove the Authorize tag entirely, do you get a 200?

Comment: This could be caused by a handler in IIS that takes precedence over what your code is trying to do. In that case your code does not even run. See here for more: ["405 method not allowed" in IIS7.5 for "PUT" method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6147181/1220550)

Comment: You have very little access privileges on a IIS.  So you cannot write data to a IIS.  A connection on IIS by default is treated as a GUEST with no writes allowed.  Best solution is to put any data on a Network Drive that GUEST can write instead of trying to write to a drive on the IIS.

Comment: There are many reasons for this error, try using failed request tracing to see details about 405 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this config problem solved

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebDAV" />
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />

            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```